# Hyperlegder Shim-client-1.0 Jar missing on complilation

Tags: maven, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Am trying to work with the Hyperlegder Java SDK but am unable to locate the Shim-client jar. See error below.

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'maven'
Information:javac 1.8.0_74 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "maven" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:16/07/2017, 3:08 PM - Compilation completed with 34 errors and 0 warnings in 14s 362ms 
    /Java/src/main/java/ZoneSDKInterface.java
    Error:(11, 35) java: package org.hyperledger.fabric.shim does not exist
    Error:(12, 35) java: package org.hyperledger.fabric.shim does not exist
```

All the sources i see online require me to download the source from a missing Git repo -≥ https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java

Edit: The source URL is https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/core/chaincode/shim/java

Was able to download the repo and gradle build to get the JAR file.

Answer (score -2):

use bellow dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>me.reactiv.fabric-java-sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>fabric-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i already have the fabric java SDK dependency, what i need is shim-client